# Excel sum formula without table - Equivalent to the Math Sum Symbol

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

Is there an Excel formula that correspond to the Math Sum Symbol? (Without the need of a table)

For example:

[image: Formula]

I would like to fill in the `X` and `n` cells, so the result of the formula above would be shown in the `Result` cell, without the need to create a table.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Is it the sum function or something else that you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` for this.

Assuming `X` is in cell B1, and `n` is in cell B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1+1)^ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2)))
```

`ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2))` returns an array of the numbers between 1 and `n`, which `SUMPRODUCT` raises each `X+1` by before summing.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Your solution works great for the specific example (+1 for that). But I don't think it would work for all cases of math sum. That's why I've chosen Gary's answer. Thanks.

Comment: Understood.  His is certainly more legible!  The ROW function makes my formula ugly, but I'd be interested in summation examples in which `SUMPRODUCT` couldn't be used.

Comment: I was thinking when the increment of i is not i=i+1 but other function. Examples: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348571/summation-skip-notation

Comment: Yep, that may be difficult using the ROW function.  I'm glad you have a working solution.

Comment: For the link you provided, you could use modulus to "zero-out" array elements you don't want.  Assuming 100 is in cell B2, this adds 10+20+30+40+50+60+70+80+90+100:  `=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2))*(MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&B2)),10)=0))`

Comment: But that's certainly not as elegant as `FOR NEXT` loop!

Comment: You are right! Now I think it is possible to any case. I know that your formula is a little bit difficult to understand, but it works and it is genial! Also, you do not need to save the document as XLSM if you're using newer versions of Excel. I'll mark it as the right answer again, as I prefer conciseness rather than elegance. You are a genius to solve this problem using only one formula!

Answer (score 3):

Use the following **User Defined Function**

```
Public Function vini(x As Long, N As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To N
        vini = vini + (x + 1) ^ i
    Next i
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=vini(A1,A2)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

For your example:

[image: vini]

Comment: awesome, but is there any way to specify the function also as a third argument? with function I mean the summand

Comment: @RicardoZorio  It would be extremely easy to pass a worksheetfunction id as a third argument.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did some research and found how to parse an expression to do the sum. This is based on Gary's Student's answer so follow his instructions and only change the code. All kudos to him. By the way, I know this should be a comment in his answer but the code looks horrible in the comment.

Function:

```
Public Function summation(lower As Long, upper As Long, summand As String)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim total As Long
    Dim original As String
    Dim temporal As String
    total = 0
    For i = lower To upper
        temporal = Replace(summand, "i", i)
        total = total + Evaluate(temporal)
    Next i
    summation = total
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=summation(lower bound, upper bound, summand)
```

Example:

Input:

```css
table {
    font-family: consolas, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>G</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>1</b></td>
    <td>from</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>summand</td>
    <td>result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2</b></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>(10+1)^i</td>
    <td>=summation(D2,E2,F2)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```css
table {
    font-family: consolas, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>G</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>1</b></td>
    <td>from</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>summand</td>
    <td>result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2</b></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>(10+1)^i</td>
    <td>235794768</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you need to parameterize a value use strings

```css
table {
    font-family: consolas, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>G</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>1</b></td>
    <td>from</td>
    <td>to</td>
    <td>summand</td>
    <td>result</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2</b></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>="(" & D4 & "+1)^i"</td>
    <td>=summation(D2,E2,F2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>3</b></td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Again, all kudos to Gary's Student.